# Cube not being displayed as a cube

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, rotation, opengl-compat

I have some code where i create a cube I then change the polygon mode to `line`. I then realised it didnt look like a cube and just looked like a square so i tried rotating it. It seems to rotate but stops displaying parts of the square and it doesn't seem to be a cube. I am not sure if i am rotating properly or drawing the cube properly or even both.

full c++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

void DrawCube(GLfloat centerPosX, GLfloat centerPosY, GLfloat centerPosZ, GLfloat edgeLength);

int main(void) {
    GLFWwindow* window;

    //Init library
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;
    //create a window
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLfloat screenWidth = 640;
    GLfloat screenHeight = 480;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "electroCaft", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, screenWidth, 0, screenHeight, 0, 500); // essentially setting coodinates
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    GLfloat halfScreenWidth = screenWidth / 2;
    GLfloat halfScreenHeight = screenHeight / 2;

    //loop until user closes window
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        //render graphics
        //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(62.0f / 255.0f, 85.9f / 255.0f, 255.0 / 255.0, 0.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //drawing here

        DrawCube(halfScreenWidth, halfScreenHeight, -500, 250); //x,y,w,h z is calculated in cube func
        //DrawCube(halfScreenWidth, halfScreenHeight - 100, -500, 250);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;

}


void DrawCube(GLfloat centerPosX, GLfloat centerPosY, GLfloat centerPosZ, GLfloat edgeLength) {
    GLfloat halfSideLength = edgeLength * 0.5;
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        // front face
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, //top left
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, //top right
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, //bottom right
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // bottom left

        // back face
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, //top left
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, //top right
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, //bottom right
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, // bottom left

        // left face
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, //top left
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, //top right
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, //bottom right
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // bottom left

        // right face
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, //top left
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, //top right
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, //bottom right
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // bottom left

        // top face
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, //top left
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, //top right
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, //bottom right
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // bottom left

        // bottom face
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, //top left
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, //top right
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, //bottom right
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength // bottom left
    };

    //glRotated(edgeLength, 0, 0, 1);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not calculate the translated vertex coordinates of the cube. Draw the cube around (0, 0, 0). Use [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) to move the cube at its position in the world. Befor the the cube can be rotated by [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml). Since `glTranslate` and `glRotate` create a matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix, the `glRotate` instrucction has to be done after the `glTranslate` instruction.
If the cube is distance of the cube to the eye position is 500, and the distance of to the far plane is 500, then the back half of the cube will be clipped. You've to change the far plane when you setup the [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) by [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml). e.g.:

[image]

```cpp
glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, screenWidth, screenHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, screenWidth, 0, screenHeight, 0, 1000);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

GLfloat angle = 1.0;
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

    glClearColor(62.0f / 255.0f, 85.9f / 255.0f, 255.0 / 255.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef((GLfloat)screenWidth/2.0f, (GLfloat)screenHeight/2.0f, -500.0f );
    glRotatef(angle, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    angle += 1.0f;
    DrawCube(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 250);

    glPopMatrix();

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

---

Any way, for a "real" 3 dimensional look, I recommend to setup a [Perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) by [`gluPerspective`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml). e.g.:

[image]

```cpp
glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, screenWidth, screenHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(90.0, (float)screenWidth/screenHeight, 1.0, 1000.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

GLfloat angle = 1.0;
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

    glClearColor(62.0f / 255.0f, 85.9f / 255.0f, 255.0 / 255.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -500 );
    glRotatef(angle, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    angle += 1.0f;
    DrawCube(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 250);

    glPopMatrix();

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Comment: This was a very helpful answer and helped me out with my knowledge of Opengl

Comment: how would i get the full cube to show without it rotating

Comment: @Dextron Set a constant angle (e.g. `angle=45.0f;`), but don't increment it (delete `angle += 1.0f;`)